# how can we increase the width of an element when the width value is dynamically changing?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, width

first of all i want to say that the following function is by chance and by this i mean that its functioning is very strange:

```
function x (e,s,v){ // e =element, s = desired size of an element, v = speed 
    var div = document.getElementById(e),
        width = 0;
    for(var i =0; width<s; i++){

        if(i%v === 0){ 
        width = width+1;
        div.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+width+'px;');

        }else{
            width = width +0;
        }
    };

};
```

this function is working perfectly and doing what i want but the problem is that the width is changing at once when the working of this function is finished.

### in detail

i want that the width of an element increase smoothly, increase 'one' by 'one' `px`. so i made this function.

there is an if statement because if i didn't put that there then the width of that element would increase at once. that if statement delay the time between the adding of two pixels

but now the problem is that it is adding pixels one by one but the width is increasing at once after the completion of the function.

for example if i write in console `x('aynElement', 500, 100)` then it is adding pixels one by one but the width of the element is increasing at once when the function stop functioning

you can see this yourself in console

link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjmbf69v/) for full code

### secondly

the problem is that this is strange. you had absolutely felt weird after reading this function. please anyone explain me this weirdness.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to do this.

```js
function x(e, s, v) { // e =element, s = size of an element, v = speed 
  var div = document.getElementById(e),
    width = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < (s - width); i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + width+++'px;');
    }, i * (1 / (v * 0.01)));
  };
};

x('d1', 400, 10)
```

```css
#d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="d1" style="width:200px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve it better (might need the one or other adjustment, just a quick scrape):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kjmbf69v/3/)**

```
setInterval(function(){
    grow('id',250) //set your parameters here
}, 100); //this is the speed - the lower the quicker


    var width = 1;
function grow(e,s) {

        document.getElementById('d1').style.width = width+"px";
        width++;
};
```

```js
setInterval(function(){
    grow('id',500)
}, 10);

    
    var width = 250;
function grow(e,s) {
        
        document.getElementById('d1').style.width = width+"px";
        width++;
};
```

```css
#d1{
  
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="d1" ></div>
</body>
```